# Use new Excel Sort Function. Return only arrays of matching results

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Wondering if you have figured out a way to use the new excel [sort](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sort-function) function to return a sorted list of data matching criteria.

For example, below I am only trying to return an array of names and values of those who scored above 50.
[image: Sort Example]

As you can see it returns those not matching the criteria.

**Desired Output**

[image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to filter scores above 50 using `Filter()` function. Then sort it by score in descending order with sort function using sort order `[sort_order]` by `-1 = Descending`. Try-

```
=SORT(FILTER(A2:B10,B2:B10>50),2,-1)
```

[image]